# Mongoid returning object as array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, tire

I am using tire/elasticsearch for searching with mongoid, when I update the index of my documents I am getting the error undefined method 'as_document':

```
@document.tire.update_index

undefined method `as_document' for #<Array:0x10a40f870>
```

I have researched the mongoid method 'as_document' and found out that it only accepts single objects. When my document objects do not have comments, "@document.as_document" returns a single object and there is no error, however when the document has comments, "@document.as_document" seems to return an array and returns the error "undefined method `as_document' for #".

It seems that when @document has comments, it returns an array of hashes.

1. Is there any way that I can return the array (Array:0x10a40f870) so I can see where it is coming from?
2. How can I convert @document (which seems to be an array) back into a single object so that it can pass through as_document?
3. Why am I getting an 'undefined method as_document'

I have a Document model with a has_many relationship to comments

Rails: 3.2.12, 
Mongoid: 3.1.4

Comment: holy naming conventions batman! So this is a really confusing one to explain with documents being documents. but users also being documents and having documents and comments which are also documents.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Logger is your homie. I would recommend printing this wherever your logic exists so you can see exactly what array you are returning.

Something like this:

```
# your logic here
@your_array = ..set
logger.debug "MY ARRAY: #{@your_array}"
```

This will give you at least a good look at what you are dealing with if you can take a look at Webrick or whatever setup you have.

**2+3.** Mongoid stores Documents as an array of hashes so that is what you are probably looking at (but I haven't seen the exact code).

I dont believe there is anything wrong with your document definitions but I would take a better look at the [Relations Sections] of the Mongoid docs[1](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html)

**More specifically to question 2:** *take a look at the operations section.*